# How to do power curve fitting in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

There is a question about exponential curve fitting, but I didn't find any materials on how to create a power curve fitting, like this:

```
y = a*x^b
```

There is a way to do this in Excel, but is it possible in Python?

Comment: There is some good sample code for you here:: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html

Comment: The sample you provided is polynomial, not power, not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do an easy transformation you can apply the usual least squares regression.

Instead of this equation:

```
y = a*x^b
```

Take the natural log of both sides:

```
ln(y) = ln(a*x^b) = ln(a) + ln(x^b) = ln(a) + b*ln(x)
```

This is a linear equation in `[ln(x), ln(y)]` with slope `b` and intercept `ln(a)`.

You can use out of the box least squares fitting on the transformed data.

Comment: Nice, now I see, that I should have modified original equation to a linear one. That makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

Just take logarithms:

```
y = ax^b
log(y) = log(a) + b*log(x)
```

and use a linear fit for the pair `log(x)` and `log(y)`. It will result on a line with slope `b` and intercept `log(a)`, just take exponential to obtain the parameter `a`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess duffymo was first. Your answer works though.